# How to run multiple commands in Linux? Make a programm?

Tags: linux, command

First of all, I would like to let you know that I am new to Linux. I did my search, but I don't really know what it is that I am looking for.

What I need is to make a simple program, that executes different commands one after another in terminal, because I don't want to run them by hand every time I need it. How do I make it? I suppose I can't just make an executable file that would trigger on double click, or can I?

**Update:**
When I posted this question I was just a kid who somehow managed to install a Linux based OS. I didn't know anyone else who had Linux or anyone in CS for that matter. I didn't have anyone to ask the "stupid questions". I didn't know how to express myself. I was looking for a shell script guide, but all I found for "linux programming" was C, which was way out of my depth then.

Comment: Please do your research again with `Linux shell script`.

Comment: This question helped me... sometimes you're so new to a subject you have a hard time putting things into a question.

Comment: Perfectly good question and not vague at all. I have studied bash shell programming and was googling for this exact type of question to quickly check up on something. In a dessert of specific, irrelevant and more complicated questions, this was the oasis of my search.

Comment: The reality is there are people out there who were never taught, nor had the resources to have these "stupid" questions answered. One thing I dislike about this site is people are often discouraged from asking these questions. I'm glad someone replied with the correct answer, as it obviously has some value. This site isn't just for the working profressional, its for everyone looking to learn no matter the skill level imo.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simple program you are referring to is usually called a "[shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) script". Essentially, you just collect a number of commands you want in a file, and execute them. You can also have some sort of flow control (loops, if-else statements etc) for more complex scripts.

To build a simple [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) shell script, let's call it `myscript.sh`, follow these steps:

At the first line of the "myscript.sh" source file put (see *Note* below)

```
#!/bin/bash
```

then your commands, for instance for demonstration purposes

```
echo "hello, I'm coming from the script file"
ls -l
```

Save the file.

To make this file "executable" type

```
$ chmod +x myscript.sh
```

and then you should be able to run this file from the command line with

```
$ ./myscript.sh
```

You'd see the output of the echo command "*hello, I'm coming from the script file*", followed by a directory listing in long format.

Here are links for a [bash tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial) and a [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/).

Finally,  sometimes you can just string a couple of commands together using [aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29), though most people just "alias" shorter versions of common commands creating abbreviations for commands.

*Note re location of `bash`*:

To find out where your `bash` shell is you can always type `which bash`, it will return a path/directory, so put that at the top if it's different. For instance if it says `/usr/bin/bash` you'd put `#!/usr/bin/bash`that in place of `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script.

Comment: Thank you! I already found few interesting topic.

Comment: "Is usually called a *shell* script". Script is a little broad.

Comment: @Linuxios You are right, that's more specific to what OP was asking about, I'll adjust the wording. Thanks for the constructive feedback.

Comment: @Levon: Sure. The only reason I'm being so picky is that without "shell" it might be interpreted as Perl, Ruby, Python, JS, etc.

Answer (score 4):

try writing a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

command1
command2 | grep 'something' | pager
foo | perl -ne 'print'
```

Save is as `something.sh`.

Mark it as executable with `chmod +x something.sh`.

Then `cd` to the directory where it resides and run `./something.sh`.

Whether you can double-click start your script it depends on your configuration, but as most scripts create text output this doesn't often make sense. Use `.desktop` files to create shortcuts to a single (!) command (or whatever filetype your Desktop Environment (gnome/kde/xfce) perfers).

If your needs go beyond some simple bash, take a look at scripting languages like the object-oriented Python or the classic *nix administration language Perl.

View @Levon's post for further details.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a script. The most common type are written in bash. A nice alternative is to write them in python.

Have a look for bash scripting examples to get you started, or look into http://www.diveintopython.net/ to start with Python

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't knew what to search for. I will look into it.